# CoreWindow.PointerPosition returns nullReference

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm trying to set the position of the mouse cursor inside of a UWP, but I keep getting a null reference exception that is thrown. [image] How would I prevent this from happening and actually set the value for the cursor.
I have been looking into this and I always find this example: Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerPosition = new Point(500, 500);

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I tried to successfully set the pointer position by setting Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerPosition without using Task in a button click event handler.
But in my button click event handler, if I put the Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerPosition into a Task, it does not work. You could try not to use Task and set the PointerPosition directly. If your exception has not been resolved after you try not to use Task, could you please tell me in what function you are setting the pointer position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to set the position of the mouse cursor inside of a UWP, but I keep getting a null reference exception that is thrown.

The problem is that you call `PointerPosition` property in the Non-UI thread, it will cause `PointerPosition` value is null. We suggest you set `PointerPosition` vale in UI-thread with [`Dispatcher`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.dependencyobject.dispatcher?view=winrt-19041) like the following.

```
Task task = new Task(async () =>
{
    while (true)
    {
        x++;
        y++;
        await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
          {
              Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerPosition = new Point(x, y);

          });

        await Task.Delay(2);

    }
});
```